# Parameter is not valid , while converting byte array to image

Tags: c#, arrays, image, byte

I want to save images in access database , I used OLE object .

The idea is to convert the image into bytes array , then adding the bytes array in the database.

this is the function :

```
    public static byte[] ImageToByte(Image img)
    {
        ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
        return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
    }
```

this works fine .

When I want to return the bytes array to the image i get an exception :

argument exception was unhandled
Parameter is not valid.

I tried two functions to convert the bytes array to the image :

```
    public static Image ImageFromByte(byte[] image)
    {
        ImageConverter ic = new ImageConverter();
        Image img = (Image)ic.ConvertFrom(image);//here the exception comes
        return img;
    }
```

OR:

```
    public static Image ImageFromByte1(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
        Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);//here the exception comes
        return returnImage;
    }
```

What is the problem , how to fix it ?

Comment: How are you putting into the database in the first place?

Comment: If you write a test for the code, and test it with some valid bitmap, e.g. a file or one you've just drawn up, then you'll have a better idea were the problem is. I can think of a few ways putting it in or getting it out of the db could have gone nipples up.

Comment: Not a sniff of database in your edit.

Comment: If you write the stream to disk, is the image viewable then?

Comment: how to write the stream to the disk ? scheien

Comment: I tried with bitmap the same problem..

Answer (score 1):

Try saving the image to disk, and see if that works. Change the filename and extension as you see fit.

Something along these lines:

```
            string path = @"c:\myimage.jpg";
            using (MemoryStream inputStream = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
            {
                using (Stream file = File.Create(path))
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
                    int len;
                    while ((len = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        file.Write(buffer, 0, len);
                    }
                } 
            }
```

EDIT: Writing image to disk works, and I guess you can see the image. Try this one:

```
            using (MemoryStream inputStream = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
            {
                using (var image = Image.FromStream(inputStream))
                {
                    // see if this works.
                    // handle the image as you wish, return it, process it or something else.
                } 
            }
```

Comment: I suspect that the image is missing something along the way, so that it is not a valid format for the Image class. What filetype are you processing?

Comment: @KaramNajjar - Just do a `return image;` and you should be good to go, or is it something more?

Comment: In this line ::: using (var image = Image.FromStream(inputStream)) the exception comes, I'm sorry I didn't mean that it works for my purpose (the second code,but the first works well), but the exactly same exception appears !!! thanx for your replies :)

Comment: I'm new in dealing with bytes array , I can't understand the error , my problem is how to save images in database , is there another way ?

Comment: Save the images to disk? :-) That's what I usually do.

Comment: I save the database in my email, and download it in form load , it has users in it , for each user there is a photo, when I login in another computer in my program I load the database,search for the user id(after he login) then show him his photo, because of that I need the photo to be saved in database

Comment: As the saving of `Image` to disk works, you should save to disk and save the path of that `Image` with user record. That will help you save and retrieve the `Image`

Comment: gmail user : the problem is that the database is accessed from another computer(by sending to the email) , then if the path is called , it will not work to the another user.